# Sorting Accordion Header

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accordion

I got Error from Angular Js Returning this link

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=uniqueFilterProvider%20%3C-%20uniqueFilter

but I dont understand how to impliment this.

Can you help me guys to fix my problem.
Im Newbee..sorry

This is my HTML:

```
    <accordion-group  class="div-recipe-header" ng-repeat="keyw in recipe_data |  orderBy:'Keyword':false"/>

    <accordion-heading><div  class="headhover"  >{{keyw.Keyword}}</div></accordion-heading>
       </accordion-group>
```

Sample Json data Return by WEb Api

```
{
  ID: "0908",
  Name: "Fanini"
  Keyword: "Appetizer"
},
{
  ID: "3232",
  Name: "Adobo"
  Keyword: "Main Courses"
},
{ 
  ID: "3242",
  Name: "Buko"
 Keyword: "Salads"
},
  {
  ID: "8473",
  Name: "Ceasar"
 Keyword: "Salads"
 }
  {
  ID: "9737",
  Name: "Sinigang"
  Keyword: "Main Courses"
 },
  {
  ID: "7423",
  Name: "Tomatoes"
  Keyword: "Appetizer"
  },
```

This is the actual screenshot on my website

https://i.stack.imgur.com/30QP1.png